# What is the most efficient (speed) way to get a digit from a larger number?

Tags: c, math

I plan to use this inside a game loop to draw the score using custom bitmap font.

Here is what I have. Now I know that I have used the modulus, division and power operators a bunch of times. I understand that using this in a game loop is not a good thing to do. Any suggestions?

```
// Get digit n, where n is digit starting from the units place and moving left

int getDigit(int number, int position)
{
    return (number % (int)pow(10, position)) / pow(10, (position - 1));
}
```

Comment: In C, `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not exponentiation. There is a library routine for exponentiation, but it is not what you want to use for this. In general, a reasonable solution would be to format the number with `sprintf` and then read the digits from the characters. Another possibility is to store the powers of ten in a table and index them. High-performance solutions would depend greatly on use cases, including any bounds or probability distributions you know for the numbers. There is no “best way” that is best for all situations; you must be specific.

Comment: Given `static const int table[] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000,… };`, a solution could be `return number / table[position] % 10;`, assuming `number` is non-negative.

Comment: In a performance critical loop I would try to avoid needing to call this function over and over. It seems like an unlikely thing to need to do.

Comment: `number % pow(10, position)` will not work because `pow` returns a `double` and the C standard does not define `%` for a `double` operand.

Comment: How are you number the positions? Is the rightmost digit, the ones digit, position 0 or position 1?

Comment: Presumably you're using this to display some number like a score. It would be faster to convert the whole number at once, which requires only one division per digit in a loop, and doesn't incur function call overhead inside the loop. You'll just have to rely on your optimizer to ensure that the div and mod needed in the loop come from a single division operation.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: position is 1 based, where 1 is units, 2 is tens and so on

Comment: Add relevant information, such as this is for drawing the score in a game, to the question.

Comment: Yet another possibility is to keep the score represented as a string throughout, and use BCD arithmetic when you increment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `int` is 32 bits, then:

```
static const int table[] =
    { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };
return number / table[position-1] % 10;
```

is a reasonable implementation:

- It does not invoke `pow` or use floating-point arithmetic.
- It uses one table look-up, one division by a variable, and one remainder operation with a constant (which a compiler can optimize to a multiplication and some shifts and adds).

(Note that `position` is adjusted in the table lookup to be one-based to match the code in the question, but common practice would be to call the units position position 0 instead of position 1.)

If digits are to be extracted for multiple positions or the whole number, then other implementations should be considered.

Comment: If you want to avoid division altogether, you can use a `switch` instead of an array, in which case the compiler can do each of the 9 possible divides via multiplication.  See for instance https://godbolt.org/z/34MM1e

Answer (score 0):

You said that you extract a digit in order to display the game score; so I assume you will use the whole original number.

You can extract all the digits in a loop this way:

```
int number = 1234;  // this variable will be consumed

while (number) {
  rightmostdigit = number % 10;
  // do something with the extracted digit
  number /= 10;  // discard the rightmost at go to the next
}
```

The above routine extracts digits from the right, so the score shall be drawn from right to left. Warning that if the number is zero, the loop is never executed...

If you want to extract from left, and supposing a fixed-length score (like "00123"), you can store the single digits in an array, then read them back in the inverse direction: it should be faster than trying to extract the digits from left to right.